# Can I create Resources property for my own class?

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I have class which doesn't have Resources property but I need a kind of resources in it. I tried to create it as ResourceDictionary and tried to work with it as it is common resource dictionary, but I get an exception when xaml-file is parsed. Should I do something special? Does anyone have such experience?

Comment: Can you provide your code-snippet and the appropriate exception?

Comment: Here is xaml-code snipped:
`<Table.Resources>
    <Table.Resources.MergedDictionaries>
                <Windows:ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/APP.Controls;component/MenuItemsDefinition.xaml" />
            </Table.Resources.MergedDictionaries>     
  </Table.Resources>`

And I get XamlUnexpectedParseException: 
`{"'Unexpected 'PROPERTYELEMENT' in parse rule 'NonemptyPropertyElement ::= . PROPERTYELEMENT Content? ENDTAG.'.' Line number '1' and line position '382'."}`

Answer (score 2):

You should not be trying to create your own property to shoehorn into the existing resource system. Your class should be derived from `FrameworkElement` (or one of its derivatives) which has the common `Resource` property on it that works with the built in hierarchical resource system.

Comment: The thing is that my class is not UI element.

Comment: You really need to rethink your architecture if you're creating non-UI classes that are dependent on resources.

Comment: I need to declare a number of objects which should be used in different xaml-files. The object are instances of one class. They have different property values. They should be declared in xaml too. If you can advise something, I will be grateful.

Comment: If you're declaring them in XAML, they should only be used in the UI. With few exceptions (i.e. ValueConverters) any classes in the UI layer should derive from FrameworkElement. If they are used in non-UI code create them in code and access them in XAML through binding or things like {x:Static}.